# sqlite3 - help for designing a better table for quickly searching for words or sentences in ~3,000,000 strings

Tags: sqlite

Suppose I have a text file which contains ~3,000,000 English sentences in it(each line will be considered as a row); what would be the best design for holding this amount of strings when we want to execute this query as fast as possible?

```
select Sentence from BigTable where Sentence like '% book %'
```

actually this query search for the all the rows in which the word  `book` is used;

what I have done so far:

1. creating a normal table; results:

   - file size: ~326 MB
   - query execution time: ~5.545s
2. creating a table and creating an index on `Sentence` column; results:

   - file size: ~700 MB
   - query execution time: ~2.231s

Comment: What if a sentence starts or ends with the word book? Then there are no spaces. Or if a comma is after it. Look for *Fulltext search*.

Comment: I just write a sample of the query; my own sql command includes all the possible situations; anyway, it's not matter of inclusiveness of command!

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the title of this question because it's not about *storing* 3 million strings, it's about efficiently searching for texts or similar sub-strings in those 3 million strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A normal index cannot help if the word is not at the start of the string.

To speed up full-text searches, create a [full-text search index](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html):

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE MyTable USING FTS4 (content TEXT);
```

```
SELECT docid FROM MyTable WHERE content MATCH 'book';
```